# Running .bat files from WSL gives me "call: command not found" messages

Tags: windows, command-line, bash, batch-file, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I recently inherited a project with some simply .bat files for building it.  However, I would like to run those files from within WSL.  In particular, it has two build files it uses in a nested fashion.

build.bat:

```
    call generated_java.bat
    mvn clean compiler assembly:single
```

generate_java.bat:

```
    SET path_to_grammar=%~dp0\resources
    SET path_to_package=%~dp0\src\main\java\xyzzy
    SET path_to_antlr=%~dp0\bin\antlr-4.8-complete.jar

    echo %path_to_grammar%
    echo %path_to_package%
    echo %path_to_antlr%

    @java -Xmx500M -jar %path_to_antlr% -o %path_to_package%  -Dlanguage=Java -package xyzzy -encoding UTF-8 -listener -visitor %path_to_grammar%\Lexer.g4 %path_to_grammar%\Parser.g4
```

I run it from WSL by typing:

```
   command ./build.bat | cat
```

However, it gives me error messages like:

```
   @echo: command not found
   SET: command not found
   ...
   @java: command not found
```

Which seems like it is treating the called generate_files.bat like a bash shell script and not a .bat file it should run with command.

Any suggestions on how to fix this and still do this from inside WSL and not running a DOS box (or whatever they call the command terminal these days).  I care because I want to run this inside my Emacs which I start up under WSL and use for all my shell'ing because it captures all output in an scrollable and editable buffer.

Answer (score 4):

The key is to type:

```
cmd.exe /c built.bat
```

cmd and command are treated as Linux commands.  You need the .exe suffix to get the "Windows command prompt".

Answer (score 2):

If you want to start cmd.exe from wsl to run a batch, you have to call it properly and give it the correct path to the batch. It would be easiest if the batch was in a folder on the Windows file system

This is how I run a batch script from wsl2 using 32 bit cmd.exe

`/mnt/c/Windows/SysWOW64/cmd.exe /c c:\batch\wslxvnc.bat`

If you need 64 bit cmd.exe use `/mnt/c/Windows/System32/cmd.exe`

Answer (score 1):

`command` is a shell builtin. From (`man bash`):

```
command [-pVv] command [arg ...]
              Run  command  with  args  suppressing  the normal shell function
              lookup. Only builtin commands or commands found in the PATH  are
              executed.   If the -p option is given, the search for command is
              performed using a default value for PATH that is  guaranteed  to
              find  all  of  the  standard  utilities.  If either the -V or -v
              option is supplied, a description of command is printed.  The -v
              option  causes a single word indicating the command or file name
              used to invoke command to be displayed; the -V option produces a
              more  verbose  description.  If the -V or -v option is supplied,
              the exit status is 0 if command was found, and  1  if  not.   If
              neither  option  is  supplied  and  an error occurred or command
              cannot be found, the exit status is 127.   Otherwise,  the  exit
              status of the command builtin is the exit status of command.
```

So, it will fail if you use it. I can easily run them using:

```
cmd.exe /c build.bat
```

Comment: If I type:
```
cmd /c build.bat
```

I get:
```
Command `cmd'  not found, but there are 16 similar ones.
```

Comment: Looks like I just needed to fix "cmd /c" to "cmd.exe /c".  Thanks.